# Highlighted lower & upper case text using by NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I having text is "**God** is great, and the great **god** absolute!, **GOD** bless me." I have displayed this text in `tableviewcell` and I used `NSMutableAttributedString`.

Example 
1. GOD
2. God
3. god

When I search text "god" it highlights text like "god" but I need highlight a text like GOD, God and god whatever it should be highlighted.

code

```
NSString *initial = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d - %d : %@",[appDelegate.arrChapterName objectAtIndex:nBookNo-1],[[arrVerses objectAtIndex:1] integerValue],[[arrVerses objectAtIndex:2] integerValue],[arrVerses objectAtIndex:3]];

        NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:initial];
        NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)",searchBar.text] options:kNilOptions error:nil];

        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,initial.length);

        [regex enumerateMatchesInString:initial options:kNilOptions range:range usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

            NSRange subStringRange = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
            [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor lightGrayColor] range:subStringRange];
        }];

            cell.textLabel.attributedText = mutableAttributedString;
```

Comment: Put your code for searching god.

Comment: You should use Regular Expression. Have a look at [String comparision](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215868)

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing your regex expression with the following code:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)",searchBar.text]
                 options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
```

For more information and example refer [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```
NSString *initial = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d - %d : %@",[appDelegate.arrChapterName objectAtIndex:nBookNo-1],[[arrVerses objectAtIndex:1] integerValue],[[arrVerses objectAtIndex:2] integerValue],[arrVerses objectAtIndex:3]];

NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:initial];
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)",searchBar.text] options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,initial.length);

[regex enumerateMatchesInString:initial options:kNilOptions range:range usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

    NSRange subStringRange = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
    [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0] range:subStringRange];
}];

cell.textLabel.attributedText = mutableAttributedString;
```